# path-finding through smoke

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, fluid

I once found a paper on path finding through a simulation that involved smoke(fluids in general).
Has anyone read anything like this ? 
I can't remember the name of the paper or the author.
If you know a paper like this please tell me

Answer (score 1):

This looks like such a paper:

[Realistic Human Path Planning using Fluid Simulation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.59.5987)

Comment: yes I just found that one also but it's not quite what I'm searchin for

Comment: now I've read the article,it was quite good altough not exactly what I was looking for